# NodeJS + MongoDB + Express - Query not bringing any results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Been messing around with the NodeJS + MongoDB + Express stack, and came across an issue with performing queries. I have some helper methods in my **index.js** file:

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server(mongoHost, mongoPort)); //B
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) { //C
  if (!mongoClient) {
      console.error("Error! Exiting... Must start MongoDB first");
      process.exit(1); //D
  }
  var db = mongoClient.db("trackr");  //E
  collectionDriver = new CollectionDriver(db); //F
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/:collection', function(req, res) { //A
   var params = req.params; //B
   collectionDriver.findAll(req.params.collection, function(error, objs) { //C
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); } //D
          else { 
              if (req.accepts('html')) { //E
                  res.render('data',{objects: objs, collection: req.params.collection}); //F
              } else {
              res.set('Content-Type','application/json'); //G
                  res.send(200, objs); //H
              }
         }
    });
});

app.get('/:collection/:entity', function(req, res) { //I
   var params = req.params;
   var entity = params.entity;
   var collection = params.collection;
   if (entity) {
       collectionDriver.get(collection, entity, function(error, objs) { //J
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
          else { res.send(200, objs); } //K
       });
   } else {
      res.send(400, {error: 'bad url', url: req.url});
   }
});

app.get('/:collection/iata/:value', function(req, res) { //I
   console.log("entrou");
   var params = req.params;
   var value = params.value;
   var collection = params.collection;

   if (value) {
       collectionDriver.getByIata(collection, value, function(error, objs) { //J
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
          else { res.send(200, objs); } //K
       });
   } else {
      res.send(400, {error: 'bad url', url: req.url});
   }
});
```

Problem here is - whenever I point to the "/collection/" route through a GET request, everything works fine - all the items from the collection are rendered. Also, if I point to the "/collection/entity" route, by providing an ObjectID, the particular item is also returned. And when I try a GET request for the /collection/iata/value, no objects are returned. However, when I perform the same query in the MongoDB prompt, the document is returned successfully.

**Whole Collection Query**

[image: collection_query]

**Query by ObjectID**

[image: query_objectID]

**Query by IATA Document Attribute**

[image: query_iata]

**Query directly through MongoDB Prompt**

[image: query_mongo]

In my index.js, I'm calling the functions from collectionDriver.js, code excerpt below:

```
    CollectionDriver.prototype.findAll = function(collectionName, callback) {
    this.getCollection(collectionName, function(error, the_collection) { //A
      if( error ) callback(error);
      else {
        the_collection.find().toArray(function(error, results) { //B
          if( error ) callback(error);
          else callback(null, results);
        });
      }
    });
};

CollectionDriver.prototype.get = function(collectionName, param, callback) { //A
    console.log("Get by ObjectID");
    this.getCollection(collectionName, function(error, the_collection) {
        if (error) callback(error);
        else {
            var checkForHexRegExp = new RegExp("^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$"); //B
            if (!checkForHexRegExp.test(param)) callback({error: "invalid id"});
            else the_collection.findOne({'_id':ObjectID(param)}, function(error,doc) { //C
                if (error) callback(error);
                else callback(null, doc);
            });
        }
    });
};

CollectionDriver.prototype.getByIata = function(collectionName, attribute, callback) { //A
    console.log('entrou no driver - encontrar por atributo - collectionName: ' + collectionName);
    this.db.collection(collectionName, function(error, the_collection) {
        if( error ) callback(error);
        else the_collection.find({'iata': attribute}, function(error, collection) {
            collection.count({}, function(error, numDocs){
                console.log(numDocs);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

I'm aware that ObjectID queries require conversion to BSON - am I missing some similar requirement when trying to query for a document's attribute?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that your routes don´t make a collision? Maybe /collection/iata/value matches with the /:collection/:entity route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning anything from `getByIata` prototype

```
CollectionDriver.prototype.getByIata = function(collectionName, attribute, callback) { //A
    console.log('entrou no driver - encontrar por atributo - collectionName: ' + collectionName);
    this.db.collection(collectionName, function(error, the_collection) {
        if( error ) callback(error);
        else the_collection.find({'iata': attribute}, function(error, doc) {
            if (error) callback(error);
            else callback(null, doc);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: You were right, silly mistake. Replaced getByIata prototype for the code below and it worked:

Comment: CollectionDriver.prototype.getByIata = function(collectionName, attribute, callback) { //A
 console.log("Get by Iata");
    this.getCollection(collectionName, function(error, the_collection) {
        if (error) callback(error);
        else {
            the_collection.findOne({'iata':attribute}, function(error,doc) { //C
              if (error) callback(error);
              else callback(null, doc);
          });
        }
    });
};